# Convert Date in String type of one format to String type in another Date format

Tags: java, string, date, split, date-formatting

I have a use case where I need to change the date format in Java. The input date will be in the form of String and the output format required is also a String.

*Input_Date can be in any of the form (yyyy-MM-dd):*

- **2021-08-30&2021-09-16**
- **2021-08-30**

*Output_Date would be:*

- **August 30,2021-September 16, 2021**
- **August 30,2021**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which library are you using? Does the input really containg an ampersand (&)?

Comment: @deHaar I am not using any external library. Yes, the input may contain "&" if the date is a range or may not if it's only a single date.

Comment: You are effectively asking two separate questions.  1) How to convert a date from one format to another, and 2) How to split a string into two parts separated by a given character.  Both can be answered separately.  Indeed both have separately been asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 4):

### Two situations:

1. a single date `String` is to be reformatted and
2. a single `String` containing two (or more?) concatenated dates separated by ampersand(s), too

I would first define a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` needed to create the desired output (I chose a class constant here):

```java
public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd,uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Make sure you provide a `Locale` to the `DateTimeFormatter`, otherwise it will take the default locale, which might produce output in undesired formats and languages.

The first one is pretty straight-forward from Java 8 on when `java.time.LocalDate.parse(String s)` is used, because you only have to use a formatter you defined before in `LocalDate.format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)` (code example included below).

The second one needs more processing, I think you have to split the input, parse each date contained, reformat each one and concatenate the results to a single `String` using hyphons as separators.

### Handling the multi-date `String`:

```java
public static String convertConcatDates(String concatenatedDates) {
    // split the input by ampersand first
    String[] splitInput = concatenatedDates.split("&");
    // convert all / both of the dates to LocalDates in a list
    List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.stream(splitInput)
                                  .map(LocalDate::parse)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // create a list of each date's month and day of month
    List<String> daysAndMonths = new ArrayList<String>();
    // get each date as formatted String
    dates.forEach(date -> daysAndMonths.add(date.format(FORMATTER)));
    // then concatenate the formatted Strings and return them as a single one
    return String.join("-", daysAndMonths);
}
```

### Example `main` showing both reformattings:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /*
     *  (1) example for a single date String
     */
    String single = "2021-08-30";
    // parse the date (no pattern needed if input is ISO standard)
    LocalDate singleLd = LocalDate.parse(single);
    // print the result in the desired format
    System.out.println(singleLd.format(FORMATTER));
    
    /*
     * (2) example for concatenated date Strings
     */
    String concat = "2021-08-30&2021-09-16";
    // call the method and print the result
    System.out.println(convertConcatDates(concat));
}
```

Output:

```
August 30,2021
August 30,2021-September 16,2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for this.

```
public static String convertPattern(String dateString, String inPattern, String outPattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(inPattern);
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        format.applyPattern(outPattern);
        return format.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is how you can use this,

```
convertDate("2021-10-03", "yyyy-MM-dd", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

#### Update

You can do the same with `DateTimeFormatter` as well.

```
public static String convertPattern(String dateString, String inPattern, String outPattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter inFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inPattern);
    DateTimeFormatter outFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outPattern);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, inFormat);
    return date.format(outFormat);
}
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is horribly outdated and just plain horrible. Starting with Java 8 use class DateTimeFormatter

Comment: I removed the downvote, but I would suggest just remove any mention of SimpleDateFormat. It should be the class that should not be mentioned - ever

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project where I needed to be able to parse ANY String that possibly could be parsed to a Date. The solution was something like this: I created a property file that contained in a list all Date Formats that I wanted to support. Then when a String came I took the list of formats one by one trying to parse the incoming String until it worked or until I ran out of formats. The solution could be flexible where for different clients you could have a different list of formats and also, you could switch the order and thus control wether US or European formats can take precedence. The solution is described in more detail in this article: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Your project doesn’t seem relevant to the question at hand to me.

Comment: @Ole V.V. I don't know how you don't see it, but the solution I described solves the OP question in very generic way

Comment: Either you or I misunderstood what the OP’s problem was.